# Querying Windows Active Directory server using ldapsearch from command line

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

Can anyone let me know if querying Active Directory server using ldapsearch, ldapadd, ldapdelete, etc. utilities is possible or not?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The short answer is "yes". A sample `ldapsearch` command to query an Active Directory server is:

```
ldapsearch \
    -x -h ldapserver.mydomain.example \
    -D "mywindowsuser@mydomain.example" \
    -W \
    -b "cn=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com" \
    -s sub "(cn=*)" cn mail sn
```

This would connect to an AD server at hostname `ldapserver.mydomain.example` as user `mywindowsuser@domain.example`, prompt for the password on the command line and show name and email details for users in the `cn=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com` subtree.

See [Managing LDAP from the Command Line on Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-ldap-command-line-linux) for more samples. See [LDAP Query Basics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx) for Microsoft Exchange documentation for samples using LDAP queries with Active Directory.

Comment: Saved my day! :D I had gotten a username (`api-user`) for an LDAP Active Directory without any `@example.org`-part. The trick was to concatenate the CNs -- e.g. `CN=edu,CN=school,CN=com` becomes `@edu.school.com` giving `api-user@edu.school.com`

Comment: The answer is nice, but as there are a lot of options for the command, something more extensive documentation is helpful. The link in the answer is not existing now, so I offer the Redhat documentation https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.2/html/Administration_Guide/Creating_Directory_Entries-LDIF_Update_Statements.html#LDIF_Update_Statements-Modifying_an_Entry_Using_LDIF

Answer (score 2):

You could query an LDAP server from the command line with ldap-utils: ldapsearch, ldapadd, ldapmodify